# How to detect snprintf failure?

Tags: c++11, printf

I am using `snprintf` to format string using user-defined format (also given as string). The code looks like this:

```
void DataPoint::valueReceived( QVariant value ) {
    // Get the formating QVariant, which is only considered valid if it's string
    QVariant format = this->property("format");
    if( format.isValid() && format.type()==QMetaType::QString && !format.isNull() ) {
        // Convert QString to std string
        const std::string formatStr = format.toString().toStdString();
        LOGMTRTTIINFO(pointName<<"="<<value.toString().toUtf8().constData()<<"=>"<<formatStr<<"["<<formatStr.length()<<'\n');
        // The attempt to catch exceptions caused by invalid formating string
        try {
            if( value.type() == QMetaType::QString ) {
                // Treat value as string (values are allways ASCII)
                const std::string array = value.toString().toStdString();
                const char* data = (char*)array.c_str();
                // Assume no more than 10 characters are added during formating.
                char* result = (char*)calloc(array.length()+10, sizeof(char));
                snprintf(result, array.length()+10, formatStr.c_str(), data);
                value = result;
            }
            // If not string, then it's a number.
            else {
                double data = value.toDouble();
                char* result = (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char));
                // Even 15 characters is already longer than largest number you can make any sense of
                snprintf(result, 30, formatStr.c_str(), data);
                LOGMTRTTIINFO(pointName<<"="<<data<<"=>"<<formatStr<<"["<<formatStr.length()<<"]=>"<<result<<'\n');
                value = result;
            }
        } catch(...) {
            LOGMTRTTIERR("Format error in "<<pointName<<'\n');
        }
    }
    ui->value->setText(value.toString());
}
```

As you can see I assumed there will be some exception. But there's not, invalid formatting string results in gibberish. This is what I get if I try to format `double` using `%s`:

[image: image description]

So is there a way to detect that invalid formatting option was selected, such as formatting number as string or vice-versa? And what if totally invalid formatting string is given?

Comment: First of all, you *do* know that `snprintf` is a C function, and as such will not thrown any exception. Second of all, you should try step through the code in a debugger, to see the actual format string and the actual value you try to pass as argument.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I pass a `double` and `%s`. I don't need a debugger to see it, I have the log messages there. And I don't understand why you have any doubts at all.

Comment: Are you aware that using a *user*-provided format string in either `*printf()` or `*scanf()` is a potential security leak?

Comment: Wait, are you telling us that you use the format to "print" a *string*, and you pass a *`double`*? How would you expect that to work?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that's what I am doing, as a test case to see what happens. And yes, using user-provided format might be a security leak, but in my case it is not an issue. Also, I thought `snprintf` is C++ because [that's what the manual says](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Comment: It's been *imported* (in a way) into the C++ standard library, but it's still the same C function that's being called. And the problem with variable-argument functions, no matter if they are C or C++, is that they don't have any kind of type-safety. You can pass *anything* as arguments, the function will still use (and trust) the format-string to parse the arguments. A good compiler can use the format string (if it's a string literal and not a run-time variable) to verify the arguments passed, but there's no way of validating the arguments at run-time.

Comment: @TomášZato: cplusplus.com... might I suggest having a look at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? In my experience it's the better online reference all-around, to the point where I stopped bothering with cross-checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What happens when `snprintf` fails?** 
When `snprintf` fails, POSIX requires that errno is set:

*If an output error was encountered, these functions shall return a negative value and set errno to indicate the error.*

Also you can find some relevant information regarding how to handle `snprintf` failures [Here](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/03/12/the-trouble-with-snprintf/).

Answer (score 4):

You ask if it's possible to detect format/argument mismatch at run-time, right? Then the short and only answer is ***no***.

To expand on that "no" it's because Variable-argument functions (functions using the ellipsis `...`) have no kind of type-safety. The compiler will convert some types of arguments to others (e.g. `char` or `short` will be converted to `int`, `float` will be converted to `double`), and if you use a literal string for the format some compilers will be able to parse the string and check the arguments you pass.

However since you pass a variable string, that can change at run-time, the compiler have no possibility for any kind of compile-time checking, and the function must trust that the format string passed is using the correct formatting for the arguments passed. If it's not then you have *undefined behavior*.

---

It should be noted that `snprintf` might not actually *fail* when being passed mismatching format specifier and argument value.

For example if using the `%d` format to print an `int` value, but then passing a `double` value, the `snprintf` would happily extract `sizeof(int)` bytes from the `double` value, and interpret it as an `int` value. The value printed will be quite unexpected, but there won't be a "failure" as such. Only *undefined behavior* (as mentioned above).

Thus it's not really possible to detect such errors or problems at all. At least not through the code. This is something that needs proper testing and code-review to catch.

Comment: All right, thanks a lot. I accepted the other answer because it directly addresses the question in title (which matters for google searches). But thanks for your help as well.